# Google Place API - Cuisine List

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

Does anyone know where I can get a master DB list of all the cuisine types that Google has.  I am using the Google Places API to do a search, but we need all the available cuisines to allow a user to search for and then ping Google.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain you need a list of all possible cuisines to allow for search - should be able to use Google Places API Text Search Service:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests

You could use the `query` parameter, along with `type` of restaurant to get restaurants with a given cuisine type.

Comment: Thank you for responding!  Correct me if I'm wrong, but that's an open query where a user can enter anything and it'll ping Google for those results.  What we were hoping for is to have a list of Cuisines in our database so a user can just select one to query, or as a user is typing out the cuisine, we will auto-populate options  - saves them for typing out the entire word or from mispelling a cuisine.  Then we'd use Google Places Text Search to bring back the results.  That's why we were looking for a cuisine master list. Or am I over complicating it based on this?

Comment: hi - I understand you want a 'master list' of all the possibilities of cuisine type that Google Places has - I don't think this exists in a single source from Google Places. Theoretically you could gather it for a given area by iterating through all restaurant results and collecting unique cuisine types, but this perhaps not very efficient - but could definitely work to solve your problem if you were trying to populate say, a dropdown, or filter or something with those values.

Comment: wish there were a better solution - if I find something I'll post it, but If you really want a list of all possible cuisines for an area (I imagine there are a TON from the Places API), you'd have to write a method to extract this from an API call to all restaurants in an area.

Comment: Hello, guys, anyone found the list of cuisine types? 
if I'm not wrong then the cuisine types I know are Italian, Chinese, French, Japanese, Turkish, Thai, Indian, Mexican, Greek, Russian